# htaccess redirection to include index.php

Tags: .htaccess

Since my server doesn't read index.php as default page, and I have no control over it. So i need to redirect:

http://www.mysite.com/blog/wp-admin/

to

http://www.mysite.com/blog/wp-admin/index.php

I tried the follow, but it does nothing.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/blog/wp-admin$ /blog/wp-admin/index.php [R=301,L]
```

What should the correct code be? thanks!

complete content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/wp-admin$ /blog/wp-admin/index.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ /blog/old/index.php [R=301,L]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: That looks like a WP framework. ¿What is the content of .htaccess file in root directory at this moment? Some directives won't do anything when appended to the end of the file.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have updated the post to include all the content on .htaccess file

Comment: OK. ¿But why do you want to redirect to index.php in the admin directory? That's not normal.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try escaping the "." before the file extension in your RewriteRule?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the redirection you want is already ruled in the first 3 .htaccess lines, although they don't look right. Try modifying those lines like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/wp-admin/?$ blog/wp-admin/index.php [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^$ blog/old/index.php [R=301,L]
```

I haven't tested, but should work.

Comment: strange. its not working. (does nothing) but thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome. I wasn't sure where the problem was, sorry it did not work.